# Starting with GWT, is it important to use RPC calls?

Tags: http, gwt, rest, web-applications, rpc

I recently followed this tutorial for GWT: [GWT Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted#create)

I am new to web development and I was telling a friend who is really good at web development that I just learned how to do an RPC call. He said that is really old fashioned and not commonly used anymore. Why would Google start out with an RPC call then? Just for simplicity? Are Restful HTTP requests the thing I should be focusing on for client/server communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can club GWT with restful services and there is nothing preventing you from doing it. I know some people who have done this successfully. All the cases I know of, the RESTful service was already present/available/implemented and GWT application was supposed to be a (secondary) consumer of the service developed much later.

If you are starting fresh, it makes perfect sense to adopt the standard way of server communication in GWT - regular RPC calls. Otherwise there is no difference between REST and RPC since there is nothing you can't do in REST that can't be done with GWT-RPC architecture.

Answer (score 4):

GWTRPC should not be confused with the old RPC technologies (like e.g. [ONC RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONC_RPC)).

RPC is just a generic term for "Remote Procedure Call", which is used for many technologies which perform - well - a remote call (and you could say, that a 'Restful HTTP request' is also an RPC, if it calls some procedure).